# Fourier transform of e^|x|... |e^(iy-1)t}|=e^-t, how?

Tags: complex-numbers, fourier-transform

I am hopelessly confused. Somebody please help? :(

The red underlined is the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your confusion appears to be that you missed the fact that they want the Fourier transform of $f(x)= e^{-|x|}$, which by *definition* is
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i\xi t} f(t)\, dt=
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i\xi t} e^{-|t|}|\, dt
$$
That is not the same as saying that $e^{i\xi t} e^{-|t|}$ is the same as $e^{-|t|}$ or that for $t>$ that $e^{(i\xi-1) t} = e^{-t}$.

When taking the transform, you are multiplying by the oscillating factor $e^{i\xi t}$ and integrating; it is no surprise that the thing you are integrating is not identical to the original function.

Comment: But it's already been integrated at that point. The part that confuses me is where a tends to infinity, and then the explanation below is that |e^(iy-1)t}|=e^-t

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

The underlined can be re-written as [image]

...and e^i(anything), is just a line of magnitude 1 with angle (anything).

Thanks anyway to anyone who tried!